# Update images with timestamp on the image

Tags: react-native

I would like to update the photos/images read from gallery or photos taken from camera and timestamp them with the date and time on the picture and also resize the image to 640x480. Is there any package available that can do this? I was able to do this in nativescript easily calling following code below.

```
var rect = CGRectMake(options.x, options.y, uiImage.size.width - 50,uiImage.size.height);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look on Expo.CameraRool? It returns media with all informations you want and Expo.ImageManipulator to resize any image. Or if you don't use Expo you can use the package [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) his imagePicker method allows you to crop the image to width/height you want.